# Question about Infinite Markov chains

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Do 2 Markov chains $\left\{X_n\right\}^\inf_{n=0} $ and   $\left\{Y_n\right\}^\inf_{n=0} $ with all of these properties exist so that the probability for infinite n values to maintain $X_n=Y_n$ is 0? is 1? is 0.5?

- same group of states
- same transition matrix
- different starting states

I was thinking that for the probability to be 1 all the values in the transition matrix must be equal.

For the probability to be 0 all the values in the transition matrix must be different.
But since we're talking about infinite number of N values, how can I illustrate this? Or maybe I'm going about this the wrong way?

Comment: Are you looking for a single pair of Markov chains for which the probability differs according to the chosen starting states, or is each of the cases a separate question?

Comment: The Markov Chains I need to find should have all of the properties stated